# How to pass std::vector<void*> * as std::vector<MyStruct*>* to a function

Tags: c++, stl

How to pass `std::vector<void*> *` as `std::vector<MyStruct*>*` to a function?

The function declaration  is `void SetDataReferences(std::vector<MyStruct*>* pVector);`

if I pass `std::vector<void*> *` as `std::vector<MyStruct*>*` I am getting below error

error C2664: 'CTagFilterComboBox::SetDataReferences' : cannot convert parameter 2 from '`std::vector<_Ty> *`' to '`std::vector<_Ty> *`'

How to resolve this?

Comment: a `std::vector<void*>` is a type completely unrelated to a `std::vector<MyStruct*>` (apart from being an instantiation of the same template, which wont help you much). You need to supply a conversion

Comment: Does your source type have to be a `std::vector<void*> *`?  Normally `void*` isn't needed in C++

Comment: Copy elements of the `std::vector<void *>` to the `std::vector<MyStruct *>`.   Then pass the address of the `std::vector<MyStruct *>`.   Be aware that, if any of the `void *`s don't point at a `MyStruct`, the function will have undefined behaviour if it dereferences those pointers.

Comment: If you're temped to do `(std::vector<MyStruct*>*)`, I'm afraid it will work. But, it's [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `std::vector<void*>` is a completely different type to `std::vector<MyStruct*>*`, so no cast is going to work.

You need to rebuild the vector from scratch, and pass a pointer to that to your function, and hope that the `static_cast` on each element is valid.

One way, given a `std::vector<void*>* foo`;

```
std::vector<MyStruct*> temp;
for (void* p : *foo){
    temp.push_back(static_cast<MyStruct*>(p));
}
```

Comment: `static_cast` is enough.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Of course it is (we're casing pointers), thank you.

Comment: @downvoter This is a fully functional answer +1... Could you clarify the issue in a comment?

Comment: @JonathanMee: I was using `reinterpret_cast` originally. Perhaps it's due to that?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to modify the `vector<void*> foo` then you could just work with the underlying data, by changing your function signature to: `void SetDataReferences(MyStruct*const* pVector, const size_t length)` (remember that `const` is left associative, so this is a pointer-to-constant-pointers-to-MyStructs.) This can be called as follows:

```
SetDataReferences(reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*const*>(data(foo)), size(foo))
```

If you needed to modify the elements of `vector<void*> foo` (not the size) you still have the recourse of changing your function signature to: `void SetDataReferences(MyStruct** pVector, const size_t length)` This can be called as follows:

```
SetDataReferences(reinterpret_cast<int**>(data(foo)), size(foo))
```

[<kbd>Live Examples</kbd>](https://ideone.com/S75dKO)

If you need to modify `vector<void*> foo` that gets more complicated, you'll need to accept the `vector<void*>` as your function signature does in the question and cast the elements on use rather than as a group.

Comment: @Scheff [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data)  is now preferred because it can be used interchangeably on arrays and containers.

Comment: Yepp. Got it: [`std::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data), [`std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my problem  from this link
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1261243/How-to-pass-std-vector-void-as-std-vector-mystruct and it is working for me.

If I call `SetDataReferences((std::vector<MyStruct*>*)(&p1))` it is working for me without getting any compiler error.

Comment: And some day, with optimizations enabled, you'll start seeing some weird behavior (crashes? wrong values?)...

Comment: @marcGlisse could you please explain the reason?